# Why do my attempts to fit data to a Gaussian curve fail?

Tags: fitting, distributions

I have some data and want to fit it with a Gaussian distribution. The problem is that Mathematica only fits it partly. I have tried to write the code in three different ways, but none of them worked.

First method

```
dat = ImportString[Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"], "Table"];
Gauss[A_, σ_, μ_, x_] := (A*1)/(σ*(2*π)^(0.5))*
  Exp[(-0.5)*((x - μ)/σ)^2]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dat, 
  Gauss[A, σ, μ, 
   x], {{σ, 22}, { μ, 300}, {A, 3360}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[dat2], Plot[fit[ x], {x, 0, 600}, PlotStyle -> Red] , 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Second method

```
dat = ImportString[Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"], "Table"];
Gauss[A_, σ_, μ_, x_] := (A*1)/(σ*(2*π)^(0.5))*
  Exp[(-0.5)*((x - μ)/σ)^2]
fittesana = 
 FindFit[dat, Gauss[A, σ, μ, x], {σ, μ, A}, x]
Show[ListPlot[dat2], Plot[fit[ x], {x, 0, 600}] , 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True]
```

> ```
> {σ -> 22.2196, μ -> 288.645, A -> 3355.57} (and picture shown before)
> ```

Third method

```
dat = ImportString[Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"], "Table"];
Gauss[A_, σ_, μ_, x_] := (A*1)/(σ*(2*π)^(0.5))*
  Exp[(-0.5)*((x - μ)/σ)^2]
fittesana = 
 FindFit[dat, 
  Gauss[A, σ, μ, x], {20 < σ < 22, 
   200 < μ < 300, 3300 < A < 3400}, x]
Show[ListPlot[dat2], Plot[fit[ x], {x, 0, 600}] , 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True]
```

> FindFit::fdssnv: Search specification 20<σ<22 without variables should be a list with 1 to 4 elements. >>

[Link to PirmaisPikis.txt](https://pastebin.com/raw/w9ys8Rfd)

What is my problem?

Answer (score 9):

It is simply a plotting problem.

As a side note, you can import the data directly from the web using

```
dat = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/w9ys8Rfd", "Table"];
```

Then your code:

```
Gauss[A_, σ_, μ_, x_] := (A*1)/(σ*(2*π)^(0.5))*Exp[(-0.5)*((x - μ)/σ)^2]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dat, 
  Gauss[A, σ, μ, x], {{σ, 22}, { μ, 300}, {A, 3360}}, x];
```

Here we come to the problem. In `Show`, you are combining two plots. The second one is plotted in `Automatic` and clips the top part (missing red curve). Simply add option `PlotRange -> Full` in `Plot`, such as in:

```
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 600}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full], 
 ListPlot[dat], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It would be helpful if you mention something about the source and structure of the data.  For example, the "y" values are all integers.  Are these frequency counts? Or are they discrete measurements at each of the 600 "x" values?

If the "y" values are frequencies and you are trying to fit a normal distribution, then all you need to do is find the mean and standard deviation of the data.  (However, you definitely don't have samples from a normal distribution.  Maybe samples from a normal distribution contaminated with a discrete uniform distribution.)

If the "y" values are measurements, then you want to perform a regression (rather than fitting a probability distribution with implied sampling properties) that just happens to have a similar shape to a normal probability density function.

A curve following a normal probability function will drop to zero quickly and your data does not support that.  What you can do is add another parameter that raises the curve a bit to get a more appropriate regression fit.  I've added the parameter `a0` below to raise the curve and obtain a better fit.

Below I've re-parameterized such a curve to avoid any hint that there might be random sampling properties implied (i.e., no mean and standard deviation) under the assumption that this is a regression problem.

```
y = {7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3,
    2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
   2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
   3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
   3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
   3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
   4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
   5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
   12, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 23, 23,
    24, 26, 26, 29, 29, 31, 34, 35, 37, 37, 40, 43, 44, 46, 47, 50, 
   51, 53, 55, 55, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 57, 57, 57, 58,
    57, 57, 57, 58, 59, 59, 58, 61, 61, 62, 58, 56, 55, 50, 46, 43, 
   40, 37, 34, 31, 28, 26, 25, 22, 21, 19, 17, 16, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13,
    11, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 
   4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
   2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
   3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
   2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
   2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
   1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
   3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
x = Range[1, 600];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
```

Now for the fit:

```
(* Initial values for parameters *)
a0Init = Min[y];
a1Init = Max[y];
a2Init = x.y/Total[y];
a3Init = 2 ((x^2).y/Total[y] - a2Init^2);

(* Fit *)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a0 + a1 Exp[-(z - a2)^2/a3], 
  {{a0, a0Init}, {a1, a1Init}, {a2, a2Init}, {a3, a3Init}}, z];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a0 -> 2.697330986650647, a1 -> 58.59524798464212, 
    a2 -> 288.7789879123043, a3 -> 853.7459256185134} *)

(* Display fit *)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[nlm[z], {z, 1, 600}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and normal curve regression fit]

Comment: It is worth noting that you added a parameter in the fit (the constant value `a0`). This reduces the error but it is no longer a pure Gaussian.

Comment: @anderstood I did state "What you can do is add another parameter that raises the curve a bit to get a more appropriate regression fit." but you're right, I should make that more explicit.  But why fit a "pure Gaussian" when it clearly isn't?  I'm waiting for a response from the OP to find out if this is a regression problem or a fitting of a probability distribution from a random sample.  Those are two very different beasts.

Comment: I agree that your model is much more relevant in most cases :). I just thought it might be out of scope (not sure).

Comment: @anderstood. What part of my answer is “out of scope”?

Comment: The title is _Why do my attempts to fit data to a Gaussian curve fail?_. The fit is reported to "fit partly". My understanding is that the only problem is a **plotting** issue, i.e. the curve is not plotted entirely (nothing to do with fitting, hence). In your answer, you propose another model which fits better. It might be useful but IMHO it does not answer the question. Please note I have already upvoted your answer though, because in the end you incidentally address the plotting issue.

Comment: @anderstood. Got it. However, I feel (but maybe I shouldn’t) that answering what the question ought to be is fair game.  I do try to restrict that urge to just statistical abuses. And mixing regression and estimation of probability distributions is a common abuse.

Comment: @anderstood FWIW it wasn't clear to me whether "fit partly" refers to the fact that the middle of the peak (in the question) is cut off, or to the fact that the curve deviates significantly from the points as one goes away from the peak.

Comment: @JimB I am a student and work in a physics departement and it was proposed by my professor that the data is best fitted with Gaussian. And I addet another parameter in the fit (the constant value a0), so it reduces the error and fits better.

Comment: @Andra Adding the constant `a0` is just fine (especially if it provided a better fit) if this is a regression problem that just happens to use the same curve form as a normal distribution but without any intention of inferring anything about probabilities from that fit.  If the problem is about fitting a normal probability distribution and wanting to infer about probabilities under the curve, then the use of `a0` is inappropriate.  That's why I was asking about the source of the data:  measured values or frequency counts?

Comment: @JimB x-axis is just numbers from 1 to 600, but y-axis - measured values without specific units (called arbitrary units A.U.). If it gives You more idea it is data from oscilloscope.